# create custom window in godot

Tags: user-interface, godot

I want to create a custom window so that I can control the top bar of the window, change its appearance and color, and add some buttons or backgrounds to it

I tried to use the borderless option, but in this case I can no longer move or scale the window. Is this the normal behavior of the borderless option, that is, it prevents me from resizing or moving the window

If so, what is the way to enable the window to work as I want it? An example of the format I'm trying to reach is avast.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Since you removed the OS way of resizing and moving the window, you will have to code your own. This is expected.

You also would have to use `Control`s to add icons, title, menus, and so on.

---

In Godot 3 you would use `OS.window_position` and `OS.window_size` to move it and resize it respectively. There are other properties in `OS` to change the window mode (minimize, maximize, etc).

In Godot 4 you get a `Window` object by calling `get_window()` and then you can set its `position` and `size` properties. Similarly, if you need to change the window mode you can use the `mode` property of the `Window` object.

---

You are actually up to a challenge for dragging the window... Godot offers you mouse coordinates in window space (Read: `get_tree().root.get_mouse_position()`, Write: `get_tree().root.warp_mouse(...)`), but not screen space. So you would have to convert them using the position of the window, which you would be changing when you drag it...

Thus, I would encourage to work with the `relative` property of the `InputEventMouseMotion` (I'm not sure if it works for this use case out of the box, but if it does not, consider capturing the mouse, see `Input.mouse_mode`).

You can get the `InputEventMouseMotion` on either `_input` et.al. See [Using Input Event on Godot 4](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html), [Using Input Event on Godot 3](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html).

---

And, finally, `get_tree().quit()` will close the application.

Comment: Thank you
If it will take a lot of work just to be able to move the window, then this is a defect in the borderless property, because next to it there is a resizable property, which, if I remain activated, I cannot move or scale the window
I would have liked the property names to be indicative of the result they lead to, which is not the case with the borderless property
As for your suggestion to add buttons to maximaze, minimize and close, I tried it and it works

Comment: @stepicGame If you believe this is a bug, you can post it here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot - alternatively if you have a proposal to do it better, you can post it here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals - Either way, it seems to be a breaking change, and thus unlikely to be implemented until the next major version. But don't be Waiting on Godot, build what you want to build.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a suggestion in godot proposals to add this feature, and I hope it  will receive a response from the developers  But I hope you explain to me how to use the codes that you suggested earlier to move the window because I did not understand well how it works, meaning I hope you give me an example of the code