# Dynamic window resizing

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, godot4

I have created a setting item on the main screen in Godot 4, but I want to create a setting item to change the screen size in the settings, and I am having trouble getting it to work, even after looking at references and such.

What I was hoping to do is to have a setting screen and be able to change the screen size with the left and right cross keys, but I have already finished programming the cross keys.

What we tried was to use the ProjectSettings

```
ProjectSettings.set_setting("display/window/size/width", 1920)
ProjectSettings.set_setting("display/window/size/height", 1080)
```

I tried to write the above but it does not work.
Is there a function to apply it?

Comment: Those project settings are only applied on launch. Channing them in runtime will not reflect any effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create custom window in godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76921933/create-custom-window-in-godot)

Comment: I looked at the questions you suggested, but could not figure out how to write the code.

It says: "Call get_window() to get a Window object and set its position and size properties. Similarly, if you need to change the window mode, use the mode property of the Window object."
but I understand get_window(), but I don't know how to change the size!

Comment: It is a property, you set the property. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Godot 4, from a `Node` in the scene tree, you an get a reference to the `Window` it is in with `get_window()`:

```
var window := get_window()
```

And it has a `size` property. A property, that you can *set*. In GDScript uou can either set it by component:

```
var window := get_window()
window.size.x = 1920
window.size.y = 1080
```

Or you can set a new size (which is what you would do in any other language). It is a `Vector2i` (as a look in the documentation would confirm):

```
var window := get_window()
window.size = vector2i(1920, 1080)
```

And, of course, you can do the whole thing in a single line:

```
get_window().size = vector2i(1920, 1080)
```

It does not get any simpler than than.